# HazelCast I can't get data from cache

Tags: spring, hazelcast

I use HazelCast in my Spring Boot application and I think I have a problem with cache because the application still requests select to the DB. I presume it does not read from cache. Please find my the configuration and my classes. Addmitedly I have implemented inheritance after BaseEntity and I have embeded object. My final entity looks that:

```
@Transient
private Long age;

private boolean agreedWithPolicy;

@EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
@ToString.Exclude
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer")
private Set<Ticket> tickets = new HashSet<>();

@EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
@ToString.Exclude
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer")
private Set<LoyaltyCard> loyaltyCard;

@Override
public int getFactoryId() {
    return 1;
}

@Override
public int getClassId() {
    return 1;
}

@Override
public void writeData(ObjectDataOutput out) throws IOException {
    out.writeLong(getId());
    out.writeUTF(name);
    out.writeUTF(surname);
    out.writeUTF(password);
    out.writeUTF(email);
    out.writeObject(birthDate);
}

@Override
public void readData(ObjectDataInput in) throws IOException {
    setId(in.readLong());
    name = in.readUTF();
    surname = in.readUTF();
    password = in.readUTF();
    email = in.readUTF();
    birthDate = in.readObject();
}
```

}

Comment: From what you posted, I don't see anything related to caching. Please share the whole repo, along with Spring configuration, Hazelcast configuration, etc. Also, you *final* code miss the class declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Each of the entities in the project inhetites after BaseEntity:

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.experimental.SuperBuilder;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.CreatedDate;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.LastModifiedBy;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.LastModifiedDate;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.support.AuditingEntityListener;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@SuperBuilder
@MappedSuperclass
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)

public class BaseEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private boolean deleted;

    @CreatedDate
    private LocalDateTime createdDate;

    @LastModifiedDate
    private LocalDateTime lastModifiedDate;

    @LastModifiedBy
    private String lasModifiedBy;
}


import lombok.*;
import lombok.experimental.SuperBuilder;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.support.AuditingEntityListener;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
```

User is a class which I have embeded:
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@SuperBuilder
@Entity
@ToString(callSuper = true)
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)

```
public class User extends BaseEntity {
    protected String name;

    protected String surname;

    protected String password;

    protected String email;

    protected LocalDate birthDate;

    private boolean blocked;

    protected String activationCode;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();

    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    @ToString.Exclude
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "users")
    private Set<Address> addresses = new HashSet<>();
}



import com.hazelcast.nio.ObjectDataInput;
import com.hazelcast.nio.ObjectDataOutput;
import com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.IdentifiedDataSerializable;
import lombok.*;
import lombok.experimental.SuperBuilder;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.support.AuditingEntityListener;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
```

Customer is the entity which I want to cache
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@SuperBuilder
@Entity
@ToString(callSuper = true)
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)

```
public class Customer extends User implements IdentifiedDataSerializable {

    @Transient
    private Long age;

    private boolean agreedWithPolicy;

    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    @ToString.Exclude
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer")
    private Set<Ticket> tickets = new HashSet<>();

    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    @ToString.Exclude
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer")
    private Set<LoyaltyCard> loyaltyCard;

    @Override
    public int getFactoryId() {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public int getClassId() {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeData(ObjectDataOutput out) throws IOException {
        out.writeLong(getId());
        out.writeUTF(name);
        out.writeUTF(surname);
        out.writeUTF(password);
        out.writeUTF(email);
        out.writeObject(birthDate);
    }

    @Override
    public void readData(ObjectDataInput in) throws IOException {
        setId(in.readLong());
        name = in.readUTF();
        surname = in.readUTF();
        password = in.readUTF();
        email = in.readUTF();
        birthDate = in.readObject();
    }
}
```

This is my configuration:

```
import com.hazelcast.config.*;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import pl.gut.mateusz.domain.dao.Customer;

@Configuration

public class HazelCastConfig {

    @Bean
    public Config config() {
        Config config = new Config().setInstanceName("HAZELCAST-1")
                .addMapConfig(
                        new MapConfig().setName("movie")
                                .setEvictionConfig(new EvictionConfig()
                                        .setEvictionPolicy(EvictionPolicy.LRU)
                                        .setSize(10000)
                                        .setMaxSizePolicy(MaxSizePolicy.FREE_HEAP_SIZE))
                                .setTimeToLiveSeconds(60 * 60 * 60 * 24))
                .addMapConfig(
                        new MapConfig().setName("repertoire")
                                .setEvictionConfig(new EvictionConfig()
                                        .setEvictionPolicy(EvictionPolicy.LRU)
                                        .setSize(10000)
                                        .setMaxSizePolicy(MaxSizePolicy.FREE_HEAP_SIZE))
                                .setTimeToLiveSeconds(60 * 60 * 60 * 24))
                .addMapConfig(new MapConfig().setName("customer")
                        .setEvictionConfig(new EvictionConfig()
                                .setEvictionPolicy(EvictionPolicy.LRU)
                                .setSize(10000)
                                .setMaxSizePolicy(MaxSizePolicy.FREE_HEAP_SIZE))
                        .setTimeToLiveSeconds(60 * 60 * 60 * 24));

        config.getSerializationConfig().addDataSerializableFactory(1, id -> id == 1 ? new Customer() : null);
        return config;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

FYI, you posted the full code as an answer...

You still miss the Spring Configuration for Hibernate. This is where you configure the 2nd level-cache. As it stands, Hibernate doesn't cache because you didn't instruct it to do so.

Please check [this repo](https://github.com/hazelcast-demos/microservices-performance) for such a [configuration file](https://github.com/hazelcast-demos/microservices-performance/blob/master/src/main/resources/application.yml).

Copied-pasted for your benefit here:

```yaml
spring:
  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        cache:
          use_second_level_cache: true
          region.factory_class: com.hazelcast.hibernate.HazelcastCacheRegionFactory
          hazelcast.instance_name: hazelcastInstance
      javax.persistence.sharedCache.mode: ENABLE_SELECTIVE
```

You'll also need to annotate your to-be-cached entity with `@org.hibernate.annotations.Cache`.

Please find the additional documentation:

- [Hibernate documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core.old/reference/en/html/performance-cache.html)
- [Hazelcast Hibernate integration doc](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-hibernate)